# Footer display position

Tags: html, position, footer

I have just started playing around with a little very simple website development on my Windows desktop using a text editor. I have made two html pages, one as a "home" page linked to the "other" page showing other content. Both pages are linked to the one css stylesheet.

What I cannot work out is that the pages are of vastly different lengths, the "home" page being 1200px and the "other" one 7000px. Consequently if I set the content height in the stylesheet at 7000px so that the footer displays at the end of the "other" page content, the footer on the "home" page is a 5800px scroll journey away.

I have tried various position values for the footer to no avail.  What might be the best way for me to approach addressing this problem.

I have posted the files on Github at 
https://gist.github.com/Pedro147/7b9427def1a44f4bd8ae

The home page is index_2
the other page is 7Seg LED circuits
style_2 stylesheet
the menu/navigation file is nagging-menu.js

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use  different id's for both pages to set heights auto in css that will set the heights of both pages according to parent elements.

Comment: Hi Junaid. I am **very** new to all this. Could I trouble you to elaborate please

Comment: @pedro147 problem solved: just go to style_2.css and change the content id height to auto(from 7000px), style will look like this.


#content {
 height: auto;
 margin-bottom: 25px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 30px 0;
 text-align: left;
 width: 950px;
 }

Answer (score 0):

In 1ndex_2 your body tag is closed before the footer though that's probably not causing your problems. Just glancing over it seems like you have everything absolute positioned, which in my experience is frustrating when you have pages with varying heights. Absolute positioned elements do not take up any height in the flow of the page. So if you want your footer to always be after the content without having to set its height, there a couple things you can do.

**Easy option:** since you know the height of the page just set the height of your content div using inline styling. Then if the footer div is the first element after the content div it will be placed right below it.

**Time consuming option:** Try to layout the page without absolute positioning by using margins, floating divs or even tables. this is not necessary if the content on the page is not going to change, but whenever you are dealing with dynamic content absolute positioning everything usually does not work.

Comment: Thanks JStephen. It looks like I have a lot of reading ahead of me before I can understand, the no doubt excellent advice you are offering me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I work a lot with dynamic content so I almost never even set the height attribute because by default the height automatically adjusts to wrap what is in it (as long as whatever is in it is not absolute position). Tables are also great for positioning because of how easy it is to vertically align things in them.

Comment: Thanks again JStephen I will have a look at tables

Comment: Junaid – I already tried that. The 7Seg LED circuits page displays the footer in the correct position but the Home page (index_2 html) page display with the footer half way down the page. With my limited abilities the only way I can get it to work correctly is to either create a separate style sheet  for the longer 7Seg LED circuits page (content height 7000px) or use an internal css styl sheet for the 7Seg LED circuits page and let the style_2 css set the homepage content height to 1200px